# Body width too wide for Ajax Content on responsive design

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have content which is loaded in with Ajax, when the content initially loads it is a super wide table, then with Ajax it changes to much smaller content,  on a PC or high resolution display it looks great, the problem is on Mobile it still thinks the body content is super wide. So horizontal scroll-bars show up, how do I change the viewport width on mobile after Ajax is completed?

On a desktop browser the scrollbars disappear once the content is smaller than the body width, but not on mobile.

Comment: Can you link a jsfiddle of your work in progress or give us some code to look at ?

Comment: did you tried with overflow?